# AWS CLI returning Unknown options : awsvpcConfiguration

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ecs, aws-serverless

When i run the below command on aws-cli its throws an error 'returning Unknown options : awsvpcConfiguration'

e.g

```
aws ecs run-task --cluster test-ecs-cluster --task-definition testtask --launch-type FARGATE --network-configuration awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=["subnet-1234","subnet-12345"],securityGroups=["test"],assignPublicIp="DISABLED"}
```

i got the below error:

> Unknown options: awsvpcConfiguration=securityGroups=[test],
>   awsvpcConfiguration=assignPublicIp=DISABLED,
>   awsvpcConfiguration=subnet-1234]

Answer (score 13):

Yes, because the way you specified it the AWS CLI interprets it a the parameter itself. But it's the parameter's value that is `awsvpcConfiguration` so this should work:

```
aws ecs run-task \
        --cluster test-ecs-cluster \
        --task-definition testtask \
        --launch-type FARGATE 
        --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=['subnet-1234','subnet-12345'],securityGroups=['test'],assignPublicIp='DISABLED'}"
```

Background: `awsvpcConfiguration` is, as per the CLI [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) a shorthand syntax, not a valid parameter (or: option) of the `run-task` command.